# How to build Breeze by command "sbt assembly"?

Tags: assembly, intellij-idea, sbt, scala-breeze

I try to build Breeze by command "sbt assembly" in intellij idea. However, it told me that "Not a valid command: assembly" which makes me very confused. Because the codes in the default plugin.sbt seems it supports command "sbt assembly"

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("artifactory", url("http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.13.0")
```

And the page of Breeze project on github also tells me that it support command "sbt assembly". https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/wiki/Installation

Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: I think you've used the wrong tag breeze so changing it for now